# Questions about POSIX Threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, posix

```
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4

void *work(void *i){
    printf("Hello, world from %i\n", pthread_self());
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int i;
    pthread_t id[NUM_THREADS];
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i){
       if(pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, work, NULL)){
          printf("Error creating the thread\n"); exit(19);
       } 
    }
    printf("After creating the thread. My id is: %i\n",
    pthread_self());
    return 0;
}
```

i know the output is :

```
Hello, world from 2
Hello, world from 3
After creating the thread. My id is: 1
Hello, world from …
```

First of all this is not a homework. 
POSIX is not my field so I just want an explanation of the output (no need to explain functions used since I know what they do) some quick answers of:

1. ARE the ids for  pthreads (2 , 3 , 1) specified by the system??
2. the `++i` used ... did it affect the output somehow?
3. why is it that there are only 4 threads in the end (3 + main) why not 5?!
4. why is it that after main printed After creating .... another thread executed??!! how come??!!

Comment: As I recall pthread_t is actually defined differently on different platforms.  I think on some platforms (Windows) it's actually a struct.  So be careful with that.

Comment: The pthread_t opaque object is also a struct on darwin (Mac OS X and iOS). It's never good to just assume it's an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I'm not sure whether it's specified, but I believe (nearly?) all thread ids are started at 1 (the main) and incremented from there.
2. No, `++i` has nothing to do with the output.
3. Since you didn't `pthread_join` the threads, the `main` function (and therefore the program) exited before the last thread executed.
4. I'm not sure precisely what you're trying to ask here, but the answer is concurrency.  There's no guarantee of when or in what order the threads execute.

Comment: so ur also saying that i can't predict the exact outcome

Comment: @Armagadon No, you cannot predict the exact outcome.

Comment: @Armagadon Correct, you cannot predict the outcome.  In fact, if you run the program a few times, the outcome could very well change.

Comment: Good summary, but as far as #1 is concerned, `pthread_t` types no longer even have to be arithmetic types anymore, so they don't have to start at 1 and increment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html

Answer (score 1):

1. They are the ids of the threads inside the current process.
2. No, the i does not affect the output because you are not passing it to the threads as a parameter, nor accessing it from inside the thread code. As such, it's just a loop variable.
3. I don't know how many outputs there are because you are not giving us the full output. I agree that normally there should be 5 threads. It's possible that some threads don't have time to print their message before the main thread exits. You should join them before exiting the main thread.

> ```
>  for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
>  {
>      pthread_join(id[i], NULL);
>  }
> ```

4.Threads are launched in parallel to the main thread. Therefore, the code of each of the threads you are starting is executing simultaneously with the code of the main thread after they are started. This means that the main thread continues to execute the `printf` while the child threads are doing their work so the output is interleaved in a "random" way.

Comment: point number 4 : are u saying that i can't predict the exact order of the output?

Comment: @Armagadon: Exactly. Threads get switched on and off the CPU by the operating system and thus their instructions are interleaved randomly.

Comment: No, you can't. And you could even have individual characters intermixed in theory...

Answer (score 1):

3 & 4: Threads are asynchronous: With pthreads, when you exit from the main function, all threads are terminated, regardless if they have finished or not.

So only 3 threads had printed before main exited the loop, 1 printed between main's print statement and the return, and one thread hadn't got that far.

Comment: is it possible to predict this exact ouput?

Comment: No, it is not possible, and the output is not reproducible from one program run to the next...

Answer (score 0):

[pthread_self](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_self.html) does not return a numeric type, but an **opaque type** `pthread_t` (which could be some opaque `struct`).

I suggest you to clear your array with

```
  memset(id, 0, sizeof(id));
```

Indeed, on GNU/Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64, the internal include file `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h` has

```
  typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;
```

But I don't think you should believe it is an identification for threads, just an opaque handle (like file descriptors are).

I suggest you to read a good tutorial on pthreads like e.g. [this one](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) by Blaise Barney

On today's multi-core machines threads [may] run really in parallel on different cores.